# CSV File Upload Ignore first line and insert ony a few rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I dont have problems with my code i only need a few clarifications:

I have done a file upload CSV that ignores the first line
[File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139045/sql-table-importing-only-first-coloumn)

```
PROBLEM:
After ignoring the first line i want only like 25 rows inserted;
What do i do?

Is this correct:
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length [, string $delimiter [, string $enclosure [, string $escape]]]] ); 

can i use my $length?
```

Comment: Just `break` your loop when you reach 26th line (since first is headers). `$length` is for optimized line reading.

Comment: any example code to break the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a for loop and ignore the first entry.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++){
   $line = fgetcsv($fp);
   if ($i==0){
      continue;
   }

   insert_into_db(line);
}
```

Comment: i havent tried your loop but am sure it should work – thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can also use load INFILE statement.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.

Comment: yea that's ok, but not what i wanted; i needed to limit the rows inserted/uploaded like amongs 1000 files in the csv only 400 should be inserted. That what i mean